# Grandma's Patience

Tags: identify-this-game, solitaire

I've been given some cards numbered 1 to 16 (6 cards with each number). Apparently you can play a patience style game called Grandma's patience, trying to build up 6 columns of numbers, but I can't quite work out how to play it. Does anyone know this game or where I can find the rules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searching for "solitaire with six suits" turns up a game called "Klondike Six," played exactly like ordinary Klondike but with (wait for it) six suits.
https://thepolariscollective.wordpress.com/2014/12/27/hoyles-six-klondike-six/

The version described on that web page apparently uses a deck of 90 cards, with *fifteen* values in each suit. So, not *quite* what you've got, but pretty close.

Or, six suits of thirteen cards each makes "Jumbo Klondike."
https://politaire.com/help/jumboklondike

Of course, this assumes that the cards you have are suited (e.g. the 2 of clubs is distinguishable from the 2 of horseshoes, or whatever). The rules of Klondike also assume that within the 6 suits, 3 suits are black and 3 are red. What do your cards look like?

Also, obviously, if the cards were given to you in a box with writing on it, it would help to know what that writing said.

Comment: Thank you. The cards aren't suits, just numbers 1-16. I don't have the box. Maybe it can be played in a similar way to Klondike though. I'll have a look.